# setting UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag on tableview lags

Tags: uikeyboard

I set the tableview property setKeyboardDismissMode to UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag but it lags. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

the simulator lags but once i tried on the actual device, all problems went away.